# Split String with multiple delimiters to different arrays in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, split

So I have a text file copied into memory that is delimited as follows:

"425,9856\n852,9658\n"

This is a long string with some 30,000 entries in total.  What I want to do is create two arrays, one for the value to the left of the comma, one for the value to the right of the comma, and then to each array respectively i want to append the next two comma delimited strings that come after the "\n".

I have tried splitting using .Split and passing two delimiting values, but it obviously just creates one array with all values sequentially. Such as:

425
9856
852
9658

When what I want is:

array1:
452
852

array2:
9856
9658

Does that make sense?
many thanks

Comment: If it's a long string, you probably don't want to be splitting it anyway: that necessarily means loading the whole lot into memory. Why not open the file using a `StreamReader`, then read it line-by-line. For each line, split it on the `,`

Comment: *it obviously just creates one array with all values sequentially* - you can cope with that : `for(int i = 0; i<arr.Length; i+=2) { arr1[i/2] = arr[i]; arr2[i/2+1] = arr[i+1];}` every even indexed value goes in arr1, every odd indexed value goes in arr2

Answer (score 1):

Since you're reading from a file, why not stream the input line-by-line, rather than reading the whole lot into memory in one go?

```
using var reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
while (reader.ReadLine() is not null line)
{
    // Each line is of the form '425,9856', so just split on the comma
    var parts = line.Split(',');
    firstList.Add(parts[0]);
    secondList.Add(parts[1]);
}
```

Comment: Or if the file isn't available, you can do `using var reader = new StringReader(text);`

Comment: This is sensible. hadn't thought about streamreader. In the end I created a for loop that then went through the first split and split again, but this results in having many variations of the same data set in memory. Your way eliminates one of these. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just split it twice to get what you want

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var foo = "425,9856" + Environment.NewLine + "852,9658" + Environment.NewLine;
        var array1 = new List<string>();
        var array2 = new List<string>();
        
        string[] lines = foo.Split(    
            new string[] { Environment.NewLine },    
            StringSplitOptions.None);
        
        foreach(var line in lines)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("line: " + line);
            var lineSplit = line.Split(',');
            //Console.WriteLine("lineSplit: " + lineSplit.Length);
            //lineSplit.Dump();
            if(lineSplit.Length > 1)
            {
                array1.Add(lineSplit[0]);
                array2.Add(lineSplit[1]);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Array1: ");
        array1.Dump();
        Console.WriteLine("Array2: ");
        array2.Dump();
        
    }
```

And [here's](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VBIxV1) a working fiddle of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx

```
string row = @"425,9856\n852,9658\n";

string left = @"[^|(?<=n)]\d*(?=,)";
string right = @"(?<=,)\d*(?=\\)";

Regex rgLeft = new Regex(left);
var l = rgLeft.Matches(row).Select(p=> p.Value);


Regex rgRight = new Regex(right);
var r = rgRight.Matches(row).Select(p=> p.Value);
```